# Which topological properties are retained by Product Space $X\times X$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, product-space

Given a space $X$ with some properties--say, for example, Hausdorff, compact, metrizable, etc.--does $X\times X$ retain all topological properties (forgive me for imprecise language, as I'm unsure of proper terminology)?

If not, what are some examples of properties not necessarily retained?

If so, how do we know this? Do we have to verify one-by-one, per property, or is there some generalized proof? For things such as Hausdorff and compact, I can think of proofs, but two properties is a very small subset of all possible properties.

Comment: There would be a generalized proof only if there was a generalized definitions of the properties, which apparently is not the case here.

Comment: This is cheating... but (Lebesgue covering) dimension is not retained. It's just difficult to rule out "topological invaraint of X is Y" as a topological property formally. But I'm confident that the properties retained by product almost always needs a separate proof, as the proofs are quite different.

Comment: In all of these cases, we’d prove more generally: If $X,Y$ are metrizable (or compact or …) then $X\times Y$ is metrizable (or compact or…)

Comment: Obamafish, I think your "generalized proof" is what Thomas has proposed above my comment. Your best bet is to fix a given property, say compactness of $X$, and then prove that the product $X\times X$ is compact.

Answer (score 3):

- If $X$ is normal (or $T_4$) $X \times X$ need not be normal.
- If $X$ is Lindelöf, $X \times X$ need not be.
- If $X$ is countably compact, $X \times X$ need not be (contrasting with the preservation of compactness, even for arbitrary products).
- If $X$ is ccc, $X \times X$ need not be.

What does get preserved: connectedness, local compactness, local connectednes, (local) path-connectedness, separation axioms $T_0$ to $T_{3\frac12}$, separability, second and first countability, to name some elementary ones.

The first need some counterexamples, and for the positive ones: we have to check them separately and many are straightforward to check.